# How to display the value of two fields in my lookup field

Tags: custom-object, salesforce1-app, lookup, administration, lookup-filter

I add a new lookup field in my Contract Object named (compte de facturation) ,this field is a lookup field that will bring all accounts with record type Billing .

My question now ,how can i display in this field the value of two fields (name) as shown in the scrrenshot and onother custom field .

Any idea please  ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is controlled in the [Search Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_lookup_config_lex.htm&type=5) - you get a primary and a secondary

Comment: but the search layout is used only for classic not for lightning

Comment: I misspoke- Search Results layout. See link above